# Time complexity While loop with IndexOf and Substring

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I been studyng DSA and Big O Analysis during last year ,but I been strugglin trying to calculate this times complexity . This is from an exercise but to make it simple I just  isolated what is causing me confusion .

Hope someone could give me some orientation.

This is the small code to analysis ,as i show examples i will be changing the word and the prefix data .

```
String prefix = "TAXI";
String word= "TAXI";

while (word.indexOf(prefix)!=0){
   prefix= prefix.substring(0,prefix.length()-1);
}
```

**Just for clarification :**

- IndexOf is (N * M ) in Java
- susbtring is (N) in Java
- From now M is the length of the Prefix and N is the length of the Word

## Scenario 1

Prefix is the same as Word :

```
String prefix = "TAXI";
String word= "TAXI";

while (word.indexOf(prefix)!=0){
   prefix= prefix.substring(0,prefix.length()-1);
}
```

Number of times While loop is executed = 0;

Though IndexOF has (N * M ) complexity ,we know we are gonna have M comparisons.

N[0] == M[0]  +   N[1] == M[1] +  N[2] == M[2]+ N[3] == M[3]

***We can say this is the best case = O(M)***

## Scenario 2

Prefix and Word only share the first Letter

```
  String prefix = "TAXI";  - > Length = 4
  String word= "TXXXXXXX"; - > Length = 8

   while (word.indexOf(prefix)!=0){
       prefix= prefix.substring(0,prefix.length()-1);
   }
```

- Number of times *IndexOf* executed = 4 , so M times
- Number of times *While loop* is executed = 3 , so M times - 1

Lets think the real number of comparisions IndexOf executes each time :

- Taxi - > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 9
- Tax- > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 8
- Ta- > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 7
- T- > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 1

Total Comparision = 26

**We could say the total is = (N * M - M + 1) ,removing the constant = > (N * M - M ) = > (N * M)**

What about the *Substring* method ?Is gonna execute 3 times ,and each time is gonna execute this number of comparisions :

- (M) Comparisions
- (M - 1 ) Comparisions
- (M - 2 ) Comparisions

So ,(M) +  (M-1) + ( M -2) +  = M*(M+1)/2. = O (M * M)

***Now that we have the full picture , the worst case ( for the moment) is :
BIG O (N * M + M² )***

## Scenario 3

The prefix exist , but never in the 0 position :

```
String prefix = "TAXI"; = > Length = 4
String word= "XXTAXI";  = > Length = 6

   while (word.indexOf(prefix)!=0){
       prefix= prefix.substring(0,prefix.length()-1);
   }
```

- Number of times *IndexOf* executed = 4 , so M times
- Number of times *While loop* is executed = 3 , so M times - 1

Lets think the real number of comparisions IndexOf executes each time :

- Taxi - > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 6
- Tax- > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 5
- Ta- > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 4
- T- > Index Of  , Number of comparisions 3

**Now here i have a problem ,where i found two different ways of expressing this in a Big O way :**

- Total comparisions = (N) +  (N-1) + ( N-2) +  (N -3) = N*(MN1)/2. = O (N * N)

Or i can think the number of comparisions like the following sum :

(N - M- M)  + ( N - M - M + 1 ) + (N -M - M + 2 ) + ( N - M - M + 2) = (6 - 0 )  + ( 6 - 1 ) + (6 - 2) + (6 - 3)

**= > (N * M - (something) ) = > Removing constants > (N * M )**

So ,which is the correct Big o for this case ? (N * M + M² ) or (N * N + M² )

## Scenario 4  - Last one

Worst index Of scenario.

```
String prefix = "TTTK";  = > Length = 4
String word= "TTTTTK";   = > Length = 6

   while (word.indexOf(prefix)!=0){
       prefix= prefix.substring(0,prefix.length()-1);
   }
```

When searchin a String inside another one ,this is the worst case scenario,where you should practically all combinations.

- Number of times *IndexOf* executed = 2
- Number of times *While loop* is executed = 1

In this example ,it will have to do N * M real combinations the first time ,that that is almost all, because as the Substring removed the last character of Prefix , now ,the second time it will execute the index of ,it will only need to perform M operations,it will find the subtring in the most fast way .

Lets think the real number of comparisions IndexOf executes each time :

- TTTK- > Index Of  , N * M
- TTT- > Index Of  ,  M

The substring will only run 1 time M times = > O(M) .

***The final Big O i have for this case is = (N*M + M ) + M > Removing the constants = N *M***

My 2 Big questions here are :

- Are  4 analysis are correct ?
- Does the second Scenario is the worst case complexity?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `i` and why do you use `word[i]`? I'd be surprised if that's valid syntax.

Comment: You are rigth,as this is part of an exercice , i forgot to remove that ,i will edit it .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is flawed. You are trying to come up with scenarios that are too specific and where the strings are too small. Time complexity is useful for determining how the time taken by an algorithm *grows* as the input size grows.

To answer your questions:

- your analyses are correct insofar as the resulting numbers of comparisons are correct (for scenario 3, your equations don't make sense to me, but the complexity would be `O(N*M + M^2)`, for more or less the same reason as in scenario 2);
- no, your scenario 2 is not the worst possible case.

The worst possible case is when the loop runs `O(M)` times, each time performing an `indexOf` in `O(N*M)` and a `substring` in `O(M)`, making the overall time complexity `O(M*N*M + M*M) = O(N*M^2)`.

---

Here is an example of that worst case. Consider a prefix made of `M/2` times the letter `A` followed by `M/2` times the letter `B`, and a word made of `N` times the letter `A`.

```
String prefix = "AAA...BBB"; // length M
String word = "AAAAA..."; // length N
```

Because only half the prefix is contained in the word, the loop will run `M/2` times (removing all occurences of `B`). The condition will be evaluated `M/2+1` times, but that `+1` does not matter in the overall complexity.

Each time, the `indexOf` operation is performed, doing `M/2` comparisons (all the letters `A` in the prefix) for every letter in the word (except the last `M/2-1`, but that doesn't matter if `N > M/2`), for a time complexity of `O(N*M/2) = O(N*M)`.

Each time, the `substring` operation is performed on the prefix, and its size  varies between `M` and `M/2`, for a time complexity of `O(M)`.

Thus the total time complexity in this example is `M/2 * (O(N*M) + O(M)) = O(N*M^2)`.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for this amazing explanation,i been taking notes ,and it makes a lot of sense !
I have 2 questions regarding with this :

1 -How do you do in this complex Analysys to be sure that we are analyzing the worst case?
2 - About the Subtring complexity ,if the prefix do not existe in the word,substring Big O should be O(M^2) . But we dont get that consider because it s not related to the worst case ,right? Thanks again!

Comment: 1 - That's the sentence before my example. The loop can only run `O(M)` times, not more, so that's an upper bound on the worst case. Whether that upper bound is the actual complexity depends on whether a concrete case exists, and my example shows one.

Comment: 2 - I don't understand what you mean. The `substring` call doesn't care about `word`. Its complexity in one iteration of the loop is `O(k)` for `k` from `M` to `1`, but since it starts at `M`, it's `O(M)` (technically `Ω(M)`). Combined with the fact that the loop can run `O(M)` times, that makes `O(M^2)`. But you probably shouldn't separate the `indexOf` and `substring` calls. The overall complexity is `O(number of loop iterations) * (complexity of indexOf + complexity of substring)`.

Comment: About the point 2 , i understand that `substring` does not care about word. What i say is that if the `prefix` dos not exist in `word` , the `substring`  method will execute `M` times and each time with a lower value = M times + M - 1 time + M - 2 times , about what i read , when we have this kind of behaviour the complexity ( in this case the `substring`  complexity ) is `O(M^2)` . What do you think? So : 

 `O(number of loop iterations) * (complexity of indexOf + complexity of substring) `=
M/2                                         * (O(N*M)                       + O(M^2))

Comment: Sorry i understand , you are saying the same than me about `substring` ,but you are doing it in a separate way .